# Zend Framework Log Errors and Others to File

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-log

I need to log errors, access attempts, etc, to file by creating a plugin or adding in application.ini, in the error staying default to not show to final users

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what **Zend_Log** was created for.

https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-log/intro/

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('/path/to/logfile');
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);

$logger->info('Informational message');
$logger->warn('Warning message');
```

Comment: @zuberSurya Wherever you want. It's probably best placed in the Bootstrap though (preferably after the autoloader is registered).